# Resolve Warning given for CommonJS or AMD dependencies

Tags: angularjs, angular, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am getting the following warning in my terminal. How can I solve this ? (remove the warning)

```
Warning: C:\Users\Sharon\Documents\MyProject\PROJECTOne\node_modules\@azure\core-tracing\dist-esm\src\interfaces.js depends on '@opentelemetry/api'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

Comment: Did you see the more info link in the message? Did you open it and follow any instructions it may provide?

Comment: @R.Richards I tired adding `"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
        "lodash"
     ]` as suggested but nothing worked so far

Comment: Why? Why lodash? The is literally nothing in the message above mentioning lodash.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that older version of @opentelemetry/api doesn't support ESM. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/11550.  The warning should be gone once the @azure/storage-blob releases a new version that contains the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts..... by adding below code snippet in to build section of your angular.json

```
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
      "opentelemetry",

   ]
```

reply me if it not works